# Can SelectionKey.isWritable be true without OP_WRITE in interestOps()?

Tags: java, nio

Given a SelectableChannel c and its SelectionKey k, k.isWritable() returns, whether the channel is ready to accept calls to write().

However, can k.isWritable() return true if the channel accepts writes, but OP_WRITE isn't set in interestOps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, ready ops is subset of interest ops. if key isn't interested in write, selector will not set its write ready op (which does not mean it cannot accept write. you can call write() anytime. with write-ready, write() is very likely to succeed, but there's not guarantee there either)

Comment: It's a different question, but under what circumstances (apart from the connection getting closed between isWriteable() and write()) could the write fail/get delayed?

Comment: that's what SelectionKey javadoc says.

Answer (score 0):

There is a catch, which costs me several hours to figure out. Consider the following code:

```
SocketChannel socket = SocketChannel.open(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 22));
socket.configureBlocking(false);
Selector selector = Selector.open();
SelectionKey selkey = socket.register(selector, 0);
....
selkey.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ);
selector.select(1000);
System.out.println("Selecting r, return " +
  (selector.selectedKeys().contains(selkey) && selkey.isReadable() ? "r" : "") +
  (selector.selectedKeys().contains(selkey) && selkey.isWritable() ? "w" : ""));
```

It prints "Selecting r, return w". So it is possible for isWritable() to be true while only OP_READ is interested. This happens if OP_WRITE is included in a previous select() call and the current select() returns 0, which means selkey is not updated.

The complete proof code is here: https://gist.github.com/wuyongzheng/43cc9dc07e13124663d1. To run, you need a SSH server at port 22.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it can:
if you OP_WRITE is set first,then
key.interestOps(0);
key.isWritable() will return true.